# Why triac output goes higher than line 230-240 voltage in AC dimmer circuit?

Tags: dimmer, arduino-uno

I am using AC dimmer circuit using arduino. circuit is working normally but the only problem is about voltage. as the dimmer circuit varies dimming,the output voltage also increases and decrease. Line voltage is 240 volt and output voltage goes till 328 volt. Is this normal working of triac BT139 or I am doing something wrong?

[the circuit is which I am using for dimmer on arduino](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-light-dimmer-The-circuit/)

[image: the dimmer circuit]

Comment: AC voltage is measured by RMS (a type of average) the peak voltage is higher.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Those Instructables articles are usually very long so not many of us will bother to read your link. Add the image into your post instead. (You can paste the URL into the image upload dialog.)

Comment: You are right sir, but triac should work as I am getting output at load?

Comment: How and where are you measuring the voltage? i.e., Multimeter (make and model) and range or oscilloscope?

Comment: Using multimeter

Comment: On load terminals

Comment: Please read the comments carefully and try to provide all the information requested. You should also update your question so that anyone trying to help doesn't have to read the comments to get all the information.

Comment: "Using multimeter... On load terminals" - what load did you have connected while measuring the voltage? What make and model is your multimeter?

Comment: Load is incandescent light

Comment: @Transistor sorry sir, will be better aware of next time.

Comment: You've done the same with Bruce's request. You gave him only one of the three pieces of information requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Line voltage is 240 volt and output voltage goes till 328 volt. Is
>   this normal working of triac BT139 or I am doing something wrong?

[image]

If the RMS voltage is (say) 1 volt then the peak voltage will be 1.4142 volts. If the RMS voltage is 230 volts then the peak voltage will be 1.4142 x 230 volts = 325 volts and the peak-to-peak voltage will be 650 volts.

Picture from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/rms-voltage-calculator/)

Comment: Got it, thank you sir to clear my doubts, I was scared when got high voltage at output.